# Use mutate() and across() for columns starting with a specific string if a column contains a specific value

Tags: r, dplyr

So in a df I want to change variables in columns starting with a string if a specific column contains a certain value in one row. For example, since bNA contains a 1 in row 3, all columns starting with b have to change their values to NA.

I assume I should use something like this, but not working.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with('b')), ~replace('bNA' == "1"  , "NA"))

a1 a2 a3 aNA b1 b2 b3 bNA
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1

a1 a2 a3 aNA b1 b2 b3 bNA
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 0 NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: please include reproducible data in your question

Comment: The code is reproducible but not the data! Use `dput(YOURDATA)`

Answer (score 2):

You need `ifelse` instead of `replace`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with('b'), ~ifelse(bNA == 1, NA, .)))
  a1 b1 b2 bNA
1  1  1  1   0
2  1  1  1   0
3  1 NA NA  NA
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  a1 = c(1,1,1),
  b1 = c(1,1,1),
  b2 = c(1,1,1),
  bNA = c(0,0,1)
)
```

Comment: If my solution helped you please consider upvoting and/or accepting it.